# Unset query when logged in using session

Tags: php, mysql

When logged in to a session as a valid user, I can select three options for events we run. One option select is "In Progress", another option select is "Completed", and another is "Canceled". My query sorts the events by `order_date ASC`. This is perfect for the events "In Progress".

However, when we choose to display events that may be completed there are many of them now (6 years) and we want these completed events to display `DESC` (this puts the most recent at the top). Just to save scrolling down so much any time, we need to look at a completed event (the most recent will be at the bottom)

I have created a reverse_date_order.php file and have copied the original code form event_search_results which displays all events in `ASC` order as stated already.

As this is being done in a `SESSION` the new file I have anchor linked to still displays the events in the same `ASC` order.

I have tried to `UNSET($variable)` but I am having no luck with this problem.

The problem is that even though my new file called reverse_date_order.php has the code to sort `DESC` as in

```
$query .= " ORDER BY `order_date` DESC";
```

the events still display in `ASC` order, which is not what we want.

I guess this is all to do with the session, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

**Note:** If the event happens to be completed or canceled, I need the order to be `DESC` - not - `ASC` only need to be `ASC` when event is in progress.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['valid_user']))
{
?>
<?php
ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting (E_ALL & -E_NOTICE);
$training_practise_area = "Training practise area";
$search = " ";
$franchise_name = " ";
$progress_state = " ";
$order_date = " ";
$venue = " ";
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>
Event search results
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require ('menu.php');
?><table(code removed here) Event Search Results</strong>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan='7'>
You are logged in as: 
<?php echo $_SESSION['valid_user']; ?>
<br />
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</td>
</tr>   
<?php
Database Connection(Not Shown but correct)

if(!isset($_SESSION['event_search']))
{
$query= "SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE ";

$search = $_POST['search'];

if($_POST['franchise_name'] != 'all')
{
$franchise_name=$_POST['franchise_name'];
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$franchise_name = addslashes($franchise_name);
}
if(eregi("'$", $query))
{
$query.= $search;
}
$query.= "`franchise_name` = '$franchise_name'";
}
else
{
if(eregi("'$", $query))
{
$query.= $search;
}
$query.= "`events_id` >= '1'";
}

if($_POST['progress_state'] != '')
{
$progress_state=$_POST['progress_state'];
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$progress_state = addslashes($progress_state);
}
if(eregi("'$", $query))
{
$query.= $search;
}
$query.= " `progress_state` = '$progress_state'";
}

if($_POST['order_date'] != '')
{
$order_date=$_POST['order_date'];
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$order_date = addslashes($order_date);
}
if(eregi("'$", $query))
{
$query.= $search;
}
$query.= " `order_date` = '$order_date'";
}

if($_POST['venue'] != '')
{
$venue=$_POST['venue'];
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$venue = addslashes($venue);
}
if(eregi("'$", $query))
{
$query.= $search;
}
$query.= " `venue` LIKE '%$venue%'";
}

$thefranchise = $_SESSION['valid_user'];
if($thefranchise == $training_practise_area)
$query .= " AND `franchise_name` = '$thefranchise'";
else
$query .= " AND `franchise_name` != '$training_practise_area'";

$query .= " ORDER BY `order_date` ASC";
}
else
{
$query = $_SESSION['event_search'];
}

$_SESSION['event_search'] = $query;
echo $query;// was commented out
$res=mysql_query($query); 
?>
<tr>
<td><strong>Territory</strong></td>
<td><strong>Date</strong></td>
<td><strong>Venue</strong></td>
<td colspan='4'><a href="reverse_date_order.php">Reverse Date Order</a></td>
</tr>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo "<tr><td>".$row['franchise_name'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo " ".$row['order_date'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo " ".$row['venue'];
echo "</td><td>";
?>
<FORM ACTION="view_event.php" METHOD="post">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="events_id" VALUE="<?php echo $row['events_id'];?">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="View event details">
</FORM>`
```

Comment: By the way it is late here in Australia and I will respond to any replies in the morning. Cheers and Thanks

Comment: show your code please

Comment: If you didn't make any other mistakes, deleting the cookie should do the trick.

Comment: Your talking about the session data probably having an effect on this – but you didn’t show us what exactly the part of your session in all this is. What values do you store in there and when, that influence the query, and where do you use them again?

Comment: Are you storing the query results in the session i.e. running the query once? Or are you storing the query in the session and running it each time the user wants the list?

Comment: My guess is that the query ending in ORDER BY `order_date` ASC is being kept in the created session. When I choose Reverse Date Order, this takes me to a new php file I have basically a copy of the file you are viewing here. This file has the query ending with ORDER BY `order_date` DESC. Problem is that events still show ASC - I am not a programmer, I just try and figure it out. Some times I figure it out and other times I can not. This time I can not figure it out :-(

Comment: I have reformatted the supplied code - added various missing bits and tried to check by inspection that it will always run the query. Which it was designed to do: **[Pastebin : stackoverflow.com -q28408706](http://pastebin.com/fxHTKNZr)**

Comment: Hi Ryan - yes thank you for advising that, it has worked like this for many years. What we would like it to do is - Note: If the event happens to be completed or canceled, I need the order to be DESC - not - ASC only need to be ASC when event is in progress.